# ForEach lambda async vs Task.WhenAll

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, async-await

I have an async method like this:

```cs
private async Task SendAsync(string text) {
  ...
}
```

I also have to use this method one time for each item in a List:

```cs
List<string> textsToSend = new Service().GetMessages();
```

Currently my implementation is this:

```cs
List<string> textsToSend = new Service().GetMessages();
List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>(textsToSend.Count);
textsToSend.ForEach(t => tasks.Add(SendAsync(t)));
await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
```

With this code, I get a `Task` for each message that runs `async` the sending method.

However, I don't know if is there any different between my implementation and this one:

```cs
List<string> textsToSend = new Service().GetMessages();
textsToSend.ForEach(async t => await SendAsync(t));
```

**In the second one, I don't have the `List<Task>` allocation, but I think that the first one launch all `Task` in parallel and the second sample, one by one.**

Could you help me to clarify if is there any different between the first and second samples?

PD: I also know that C#8 supports foreach async, however I'm using C# 7

Comment: The second one isn't going to work correctly as `ForEach` cannot work with async delegate so it will be converted to `Action` which in turn cannot be awaited.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't even need a list, much less ForEach to execute multiple tasks and await all of them. In any case, `ForEach` is just a convenience function that uses `foreach.

To execute some async calls *concurrently* bases on a list of inputs all you need is `Enumerable.Select`. To await all of them to complete you only need `Task.WhenAll`  :

```
var tasks=textsToSend.Select(text=>SendAsync(text));
await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
```

LINQ and IEnumerable in general use lazy evaluation which means `Select`'s code won't be executed until the returned IEnumerable is iterated. In this case it doesn't matter because it's iterated in the very next line. If one wanted to force all tasks to start a call to `ToArray()` would be enough, eg :

```
var tasks=textsToSend.Select(SendAsync).ToArray();
```

If you wanted to execute those async calls sequentially, ie one after the other, you could use a simple foreach. There's no need for C# 8's `await foreach` :

```
foreach(var text in textsToSend)
{
    await SendAsync(text);
}
```

**The Bug**

This line is simply a bug :

```
textsToSend.ForEach(async t => await SendAsync(t));
```

`ForEach` doesn't know anything about tasks so it never awaits for the generated tasks to complete. In fact, the tasks can't be awaited at all. The `async t` syntax creates an `async void` delegate. It's equivalent to :

```
async void MyMethod(string t)
{
    await SendAsync(t);
}

textToSend.ForEach(t=>MyMethod(t));
```

This brings all the problems of `async void` methods. Since the application knows nothing about those `async void` calls, it could easily terminate before those methods complete, resulting in NREs, `ObjectDisposedException`s and other weird problems.

For reference check David Fowler's [Implicit async void delegates](https://github.com/davidfowl/AspNetCoreDiagnosticScenarios/blob/master/AsyncGuidance.md#implicit-async-void-delegates)

**C# 8 and await foreach**

C# 8's IAsyncEnumerable would be useful in the sequential case, if we wanted to return the results of each async operation in an iterator, as soon as we got them.

Before C# 8 there would be no way to avoid awaiting for all results, even with sequential execution. We'd have to collect all of them in a list. Assuming each operation returned a string, we'd have to write  :

```
async Task<List<string> SendTexts(IEnumerable<string> textsToSend)
{
    var results=new List<string>();
    foreach(var text in textsToSend)
    {
        var result=await SendAsync(text);
        results.Add(result);
    }
}
```

And use it with :

```
var results=await SendTexts(texts);
```

In C# 8 we can return individual results and use them asynchronously. We don't need to cache the results before returning them either :

```
async IAsyncEmumerable<string> SendTexts(IEnumerable<string> textsToSend)
{
    foreach(var text in textsToSend)
    {
        var result=await SendAsync(text);
        yield return;
    }
}


await foreach(var result in SendTexts(texts))
{
   ...
}
```

`await foreach` is only needed to *consume* the IAsyncEnumerable result, not produce it

Comment: A note that may be useful for developers with small LINQ experience (not the author of this answer of course!). The line `var tasks = textsToSend.Select(text => SendAsync(text))` doesn't create any tasks. It creates a deferred LINQ enumerable of tasks. The tasks are created at the call `Task.WhenAll(tasks)`. This method materializes the deferred enumerable that receives as argument, by converting it to an array of tasks, before doing anything else.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias that's why I wrote it like this. There are more important issues in the OP's code though, like the `async void` bug

Comment: Btw I upvoted your answer. Someone else is the downvoter. :-)

Comment: In the last snippet, is `var results=new List<string>();` even needed? (Didn't DV, neither)

Comment: @Fildor no it's not, but editing a long answer is like touch-typing while watching the *previous* page - actually, it's not "like", it's exactly like that

Comment: I know what you mean. Didn't dare to just edit it out, though. Excellent answer, btw. Made me aware of that "async void" - learning something every day :D

Comment: Thanks for this great answer, I have to read the David Fowler guide again :S

Comment: David Fowler's [Async Guidance](https://github.com/davidfowl/AspNetCoreDiagnosticScenarios/blob/master/AsyncGuidance.md) is really good! I am not sure I agree with all his GOODs and BADs, but he is certainly offering food for thought.

Answer (score 1):

> that the first one launch all Task in parallel

Correct. And `await Task.WhenAll(tasks);` waits for all messages are sent.

The second one also sends messages in parallel but doesn't wait for all messages are sent since you don't await any task.

In your case:

```
textsToSend.ForEach(async t => await SendAsync(t));
```

is equivalent to

```
textsToSend.ForEach(t => SendAsync(t));
```

the `async t => await SendAsync(t)` delegate may return the task (it depends on assignable type) as `SendAsync(t)`. In case of passing it to `ForEach` both `async t => await SendAsync(t)` and `SendAsync(t)` will be translated to `Action<string>`.

Also the first code will throw an exception if any SendAsync throws an excepion. In the second code any exception will be ignored.

Comment: `ForEach(async t => await SendAsync(t));` doesn't return any tasks, it's an `async void` delegate.

Comment: I wrote `async t => await SendAsync(t)` returns the task. It is an anonymous method that can be assigned to `Func<string, Task>` And there is no difference when using it and SendAsync(t) in `ForEach` method. They both just return the task that is ignored.

Comment: Unfortunately not. [List.ForEach](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.foreach?view=netframework-4.8) doesn't return *anything* and only accepts an `Action<T>`. The `async t=>` syntax *can't* be translated to `async Task` without causing a compilation error, so `async void` is generated. That's one of the async gotchas explained by David Fowler: [implicit async void delegates](https://github.com/davidfowl/AspNetCoreDiagnosticScenarios/blob/master/AsyncGuidance.md#implicit-async-void-delegates)

Comment: I didn't wrote that `List.ForEach` returns something. OK. Regarding delegate  a refinement added to be more accurate.